# Exibir em um MessageDialog o conteúdo de List<String> mensagem = new ArrayList<String>();

Tags: java, array, string, swing, lista

Boa noite,
Preciso exibir em um Message Dialog o conteúdo do array mensagem:

```
List<String> mensagem = new ArrayList<String>();
```

No decorrer do código acrescento alguns textos ao array como:

```
mensagem.add(" o metodo" + m1.getName()+" precisa ser alterado\n");

mensagem.add(" a classe" + m1.getName()+" precisa ser alterado\n");
```

Tenho o método que retorna ela:

```
public String getMsg() {
    return mensagem.toString();
}
MessageDialog.openInformation(window.getShell(), "Teste", vs.getMsg());
```

E quando vou exibi-la no MessageDialog aparece com um colchete no inicio e no final , além disso quando tenho mais de um termo eles aparecem separados por vírgulas. Como :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que não aparecesse o [] e nem as vírgulas , porém olhando no cogido não é possível ver de onde vem essa informação.

Alguém poderia me explicar como remover essa informação?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você executa:

```
 return mensagem.toString();
```

Você retorna uma string do Array que criou, para imprimir as mensagens você precisará alterar esse sua função para:

```
public String getMsg() {
    String message = "";
    for(String item : mensagem) {
        message += item;
    }
   return message;
}
```

Comment: Ok, deu certo . Obrigada

Comment: Marca minha resposta como certa.